# Does the File system affect applications portability ?

Tags: file-io, operating-system, filesystems, portability

When we use file handling API in any programming language,i assume that will translate in the binary file to a File I/O request that the OS will service for you.

Logically, your final binary executable should be agnostic to what file system the host OS is using.

Is that the case or does the File system actually affect the portability of applications ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As so often, the answer is "yes and no" - let me elaborate:

Different file systems have different properties, e.g. max file size, case sensitivity of a file name, number of file system objects sharing a file name, most possibly more.

Now as long as you only use the common subset of these features, i.e. file size below 2G, no file names that differ only in capitalization (and always use the same capitalization), small subset of characters in the file name, etc. it will be rather unlikely, that you run into portability trouble.

But the moment you use any advanced feature, you might easily run into trouble. Windows tends to do odd things when confronted with requests to write 4G+1 bytes onto a FAT disk, on ext3 `my.pdf` and `my.PDF` are different files, that can easily live in the same directory.

Comment: Also no path separators allowed.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp I beg to dissagree: The Path separator is not a property of the file system, but of the operating system: One and the same FAT filesystem will use `\ ` on Windows and `/` on a Unix-type system.

Comment: Thank you for your correction. Yes and no. Strictly speaking you are correct, but from OP's point of view, when he writes a platform-agnostic code, he interacts with the OS rather than directly with the filesystem.